# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

Hello i am learning Python 3.4 and i am just understanding the Basics. I have a problem with this first simple code of multiplication.

```
num_1=input("Enter the first number")
num_2=input("Enter the second number")

print("The first number multliplies with the second number")
print(num_1*num_2)
```

Its showing this error: 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
What should be the solution can anyone provide an answer.
Thank you.

P.S: In one of the videos i saw, the tutor teaching in Python 2.7 in Win 7 and i can't get Python 2.7 to install in Winxp. So i had to install Pyton 3.4. Just another question, how do i get it to install in Winxp.

Comment: The phrase "Just another question" almost _always_ means you should be asking another question, separate from this one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type cast the input on python3 so:

```python
num_1=int(input("Enter the first number")) #int() typecasts the input as an integer
num_2=int(input("Enter the second number"))

print("The 1st no multliplies with the 2nd no")
print(num_1*num_2)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I wasn't able to find the list of changes in the python documentation, although i am a beginner, i will take things slowly. They changed few things, but i am glad i could find something here. Other thing, how can i install Python 2.7 in winxp.

Comment: check out these guides on [wiki.python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download)